# Java Runnable Implementation

Tags: java

I have the following program, and I need to implement Runnable. The issue is that I call the start() method in a second class, and I get an error. The Error says that it does not recognize the symbol: method start().

```
class MyBall  implements Runnable {

public MyBall(){}

@Override
public void run() {}

public void draw(Graphics g){}

}


class MyBallWindow extends JFrame {

MyBall myBall[];
public MyBallWindow(){

    myBall = new MyBall[2];
    myBall[0] = new MyBall(00, 0, 300, this, Color.red);

    myBall[1] = new MyBall(100, 0, 400, this, Color.yellow);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        myBall[i].start();//this is the error it does not recognize it.
    }

}

public void paint(Graphics g){}

}



public class runningBalls  {
public static void main(String [] args){ 
    new MyBallWindow(); }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to start a thread? A `Runnable` is what runs inside a thread, so you still need the actual thread, for example `new Thread(myBall[i]).start();`.

Comment: Try this: `new Thread(myBall[i]).start()`

Comment: (If you *don't* want to control a separate thread, but just want `myBall[0]`'s `run()` to run, just invoke (wait for it…) `myBall[0].run()`.)

Comment: @Kayaman. Thank you it solved my issue. I appreciate your help.